# PHP displaying date is one day forward after format

Tags: php

When I retrieve a date from a my_sqli query and format it it becomes one day forward. The date is saving correctly to the server, and echoing it before the new format is correct.

```
$date = "SELECT date FROM blogtable WHERE id = $artID";
$dateEx = mysqli_query($con, $date);
while($dateGet = mysqli_fetch_array($dateEx))
{
    //This is in YYYY-mm-dd
 $dateGet['date'];//If I echo this, it is correct   
}
$source = $dateGet;
$newDate = new DateTime($source);
echo $newDate->format('M-d-Y');
```

So for example if I tried to use it today(the 24th), it would save correctly, but after the format, display as the 25th.

Comment: `$source` being an array perhaps? Shouldn't it be `$source=$dateGet['date'];`?

Comment: Yep, replacing just $dateGet['date'] with your line worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrikken's suggestion worked, changing the statement in the while to $source=$dateGet['date']; and deleting the $source = $dateGet;.